# Do I have to list a country each time I visited it for UK visa application, or can I just list it once to say I've been there?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am a Canadian. I will be studying in the UK this fall. The question on the visa application specifically asks *"Have you visited any other countries in the past 10 years?"* It then ask for the date and length of travel. If I have visited a country more than once, do I say so, or do I just record it once?

Comment: You list each visit

Answer (score 7):

You should state the date/duration of every visit in the past 10 years (or up to what is specified in the latest guidance and/or allowed in the system), even if they were to the same country.

The [guidance notes to complete form VAF2](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/562983/VAF2_Form_Guidance_October_2016.pdf) (the paper equivalent of your online Tier 4 visa application form, now only available to North Korea residents) says the following:

> **7.2 Have you travelled outside your country of residence, excluding the UK, in
>   the last 10 years?**
>
> Answer Yes/No. You should include travel for study, training, business trips etc.
>   When giving this information please provide details of all your trips abroad that you
>   have not described in answer to question 7.1.

Hence they are expecting the list of trips, but not merely the list of countries you have visited.

Comment: That's an assumption. While it couldn't hurt to include all trips, "other country" means what it says.

Comment: @uberqe Please can you clarify which part of the answer is an assumption in your opinion? I can try and further clarify it. I totally agree that "other country" should be taken at face value when answering the yes/no part of the question, though with the guidance telling one to provide details of all of their trips, I see it as a harder requirement than "couldn't hurt" to do so, which makes me a bit puzzled...

Comment: The guidance is for the paper version of the form which is not the same as the one referred to in the original question. Many questions on this form are different from the ones on the Access UK website which is not the same as the Visa4UK website for the same type of application. For example, the paper form does not separate trips to premium destinations to make it part of another question. On the online Accessuk version, the applicant is specifically told to list only his/last three “visits” to these. IMO the UK application process is vague and requirements/questions frequently change.

Comment: @uberqe That makes more sense to me, thank you for clarifying. I don't have immediate access to the forms on different platforms but I agree the questions, guidances, and form itself frequently change. I don't think your observation contradicts the essence of the answer to OP's question (i.e. list each visits instead of list of countries if you visit the same country multiple times), but I will try to reword it to direct readers to the latest guidance to make the answer last longer. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no official guidance for the Access UK or visa4UK forms. The instructions (as ambiguous as they are) are embedded in the forms themselves.